# How to make JScrollPane fit to my jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist, space

I have a problem with JScrollPane when it is used with JTable. How can I make it such that the the scrollPane doesn't have a blank space below the JTable as can be seen in the picture

[image]

Also,I am currently using a JTabPane that contains 2 JPanels, one for the JScrollPane and one for the JList at the bottom. Is this the right way to do things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524224/230513), may be useful in this context.

Comment: See also this nearby [alternative approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6524281/230513).