# Jtable not scrolling in a JDialog with NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm using a jTable in a JDialog, when I need to use the scrollbars it drags the JDialgo instead of the rows. I'm using NetBeans form design.

P.D. Of course ny JTable is inside a JScrollPane.

[image: Window before dragging the scrollpane]

[image: After dragging]

Comment: Show us some code. Otherwise, we have no idea how we can help.

Answer (score 2):

Edited: On Mac OS X, this is a feature when you specify `setUndecorated(true)`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166500/230513). Use `setUndecorated(false)` instead. As long as you use a layout manager and `pack()` the dialog, the `JTable` should adopt a reasonable size. You can use `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10809454/230513), if required. See also these [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: Oops, I think the effect is due to `setUndecorated(true)`, updated above. I should have looked at your screenshots more carefully; I apologize for the error. If you still see a problem, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.