# JScrollPane is larger than JTable row

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I use this  statement to assign a scrollPane to a Jtable. However when I add the scrollPane to any other JPanel. The height of the scrollPane is much larger than the table height.

```
JPanel tablepane=new JPanel();
tableau= new JTable();
tableau.setModel(model);
tableC=new JScrollPane();
tableC.setViewportView(tableau);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAdZB.png]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shrink JScroll Pane to same Height as JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523974/shrink-jscroll-pane-to-same-height-as-jtable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it the exact size then you can use:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

after you load the data into the table.